# Workstation running 8 screens

Tags: desktop, multiple-monitors

I'd like to build a [workstation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workstation) with a minimum of 6 1080p screens.
The GTX 1050 Ti has a max resolution of 7680x4320; this should suffice for future upgrades.

If we're splitting the workloads by the 80-20 rule:

80%: Confined to web browsing, potentially offline office applications (MS word, electron apps like Slack). The intention is to keep many tabs open, so this may be a consideration if hardware acceleration is of significant enough benefit to warrant a better GPU. Unlikely to have more than a single active youtube video at a time, though likely a fair few cached / in suspended processes. Video calls are quite likely, though I'm under the impression encoders/decoders are their own circuits that don't compete with other functions.

20%: 1-2 instances of a LaTeX editor, MATLAB or Python open; a mix of data visualisation, numerical analysis or agent based simulations.

Monitors: The plan is for an arrangement similar to the [financial rigs at Optiver](https://www.google.com/search?q=optiver%20multiple%20monitors&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjLs86H2NvvAhVzluYKHU6uApEQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=optiver%20multiple%20monitors&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECAAQGFChnAFYhLABYISxAWgBcAB4AIABxAKIAcgakgEIMC4xMy4zLjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=JAZlYMuRA_OsmgfO3IqICQ&bih=649&biw=1366&rlz=1CAGUZK_enAU947#imgrc=1pOcU3y2lXiiDM).
Depending on cost-effectiveness, I may move to having fewer screens of higher resolutions.
I'm not averse to the dual graphics cards, however the price increases in computer hardware have been disportionately larger amongst GPUs. I'm unsure how concerned I should be of supply availability.

Comment: With most PCs in the last 3-7 years, with the right settings, you ought to be able to use the onboard graphics - for up to 3 additional screens, and many modern integrated CPUs will do that fairly easily. While the current situation on GPUs is terrible, OEMs don't seem as badly affected as the enthusiast market

Answer (score 0):

The gtx 1050ti supports a maximum of four monitors in any configuration. so the minimum of 6 screens will not be obtainable

In theory the maximum supported resolution should be divisible properly, for example in 4, 3840x2160(4k) monitors. If you are limited in physical connections. DisplayPort supports daisy chaining. The monitor does need a supported DisplayPort out to support this as well though.

Comment: OP could put two 1050ti's though... :)

Comment: @Salocor That's true. Though I tried to answer the question based on a single gtx1050TI. There are several other options, The easiest,like you said being multi gpu(even a gt710 would be enough for non primary monitors) or going for an amd gpu, the more recent series(I think HD70xx and up) support 6 displays. Personally I'd go for three large 4k displays and use an app like divvy to make window management easier

Comment: I wouldn’t use a GT 710.  They don’t have much processing power or very good IO (I think they still ship with VGA).  If you were to use a separate GPU, I’d get a used GTX 570 or maybe a GTX 650 Ti.  Something that’s a little more powerful and has better IO than a GT series GPU.